# The code generates star based user rating. However, the stars are aligned to extreme right

Tags: html, css

The code generates a star-based user rating. However, the stars are aligned to the extreme right.

I tried changing the float: right to left, position: center, but this causes the hovering in the opposite direction.

CSS part:-

```css
    fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    body{ margin: 20px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

   

    .rating { 
    border: none;
    }

    .rating > input { display: none; } 
    .rating > label:before { 
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
 
    content: "\f005";
    }
    .rating > label .float_center{ 
    color: #ddd; 
    float: left;
    }
    .rating > input:checked ~ label, 
    .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, 
    .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FF0000;  }

    .rating > input:checked + label:hover,
    .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
    .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, 
    .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #B22222;  }
```

```html
    <h2>
    <fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = 
    "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
   
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = 
    "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
   
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = 
    "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = 
    "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
   
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = 
    "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    </fieldset>
    </h2>
```

I've tried changing the float:right; to left, and also tried to replace it with position: center. Any thoughts on using the RTL function? newbie here!

Comment: Why use floats at all? This appears to work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jx9mtqw4/1/

Comment: Updated to be inline: https://jsfiddle.net/jx9mtqw4/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the rtl function. Just a minor CSS tweak will suffice.

Adding the following code should solve the issue.

```
.rating {
    float: left;
}
.full {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Hey my mistake, I should have mentioned i need it center aligned. Your code works fine, the stars are left aligned. I need them center aligned.

Comment: .rating { 
     border: none;
     position: center;
     }

Comment: this aligns the stars to the center, however the hovering is reversed, works in the opposite direction.

Comment: I'm glad that worked out. Accept the answer if you feel it was right and upvote it.